# flutter_blue: set_notification and read_characteristic errors on Android, BLE device disconnects on first connection attempt

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been working with flutter for a few weeks now and am attempting to build an app to communicate with a power bank over BLE. In its current state, it works correctly on iOS. On android, *partly* due to the BLE device's behavior, I'm having exceptions thrown during the connect/discover phases.

### Details and Versioning

- Flutter: 1.17.5
- [flutter_blue](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue): 0.7.2
- target Android device: Google Pixel 3A running Android 10
- target iOS device: iPhone XS running 13.6, iPhone 6s running iOS 12

### Code

```dart
void connect(String deviceId) async {
    var dev = devices[deviceId];
    if (connectedDevices[deviceId] != null) return;
    await dev.device.connect(autoConnect: false);

    dev.connection = dev.device.state.listen((state) async {
      dev.deviceState = state;
      notifyListeners();
      if (state == BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected) {
        connectedDevices[dev.id] = null;
        await dev.dispose();
        notifyListeners();
      }

      if (state == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
        dev.services = await dev.device.discoverServices();
        for (BluetoothService service in dev.services) {
          // set services based on uuid
        }
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic
            in dev.deviceInfoService.characteristics) {
          // set characteristics from services
        }
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic
            in dev.notificationService.characteristics) {
          switch (characteristic.uuid.toString()) {
            case notificationServiceCharacteristic:
              dev.notificationServiceCharacteristic = characteristic;
              if (!dev.notificationServiceCharacteristic.isNotifying) {
                await dev.notificationServiceCharacteristic
                    .setNotifyValue(true);
                dev.valueChangedSubscription = dev
                    .notificationServiceCharacteristic.value
                    .listen((value) {
                  _onValuesChanged(dev, value);
                  notifyListeners();
                });
                connectedDevices[dev.id] = dev;
              }
              break;
            case writeCharacteristic:
              dev.writeCharacteristic = characteristic;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
        notifyListeners(); //using scopedModel for handling state
        await readServiceCharacteristics(dev);
      }
    });
  }
```

### What should happen

The program connects to the device. Upon connecting (state == BluetoothDeviceState.connected), services and characteristics are discovered. When the notification service is found, turn notifications on with a callback to process data. After doing this, read from read-only characteristics.

### What is happening

On iOS devices, there are no apparent errors. The program functions normally; albeit with the initial disconnect caused by the BLE device. Attempting to reconnect works successfully without fail.

On Android:
Exception thrown: `/flutter ( 1557): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(set_notification_error, error when writing the descriptor, null)`

Line responsible:

```
await dev.notificationServiceCharacteristic
                    .setNotifyValue(true);
```

### Why is happening / BLE device bug

In my research, I seem to have figured out one of the causes of the bug. The BLE device, for whatever reason, does not complete the connection process on the first connection attempt. Typical connections work as follows:

- Connect called
- Device Connected
- Service Discovery / Notification section of code is called
- Device is disconnected
- Connect called again
- Discovery / Notification section runs properly and device maintains connection
- Program receives notifications

### Debugging Steps

- Firstly, I switch from a `forEach` to a `for(BluetoothService service in dev.services)` "for-in" style as this ensures the iteration waits for callback/return.
- In debugging, I can use breakpoints to assure the program doesn't throw an exception. By placing a breakpoint at the await line and waiting for a second or two, it works without issue. Running the code without a breakpoint set throws the error every time, without fail.
- I've built a bare-bones PoC with just RaisedButtons to call the init, scan, connect, and disconnect functions. The error is still present
- It's clear that in the StreamListener for the device's state that it goes from

  - Connected
  - Disconnected (at this point I can logically stop by disconnecting and disposing the connection or letting it attempt again by commenting this out)
  - In the case I don't dispose and disconnect, it switches to connected again

### Thoughts

While I know that this issue is partially caused by the BLE device itself, I'm wondering if there's any way to fix this or workaround it. One idea I'm thinking of is a means to terminate the asynchronous calls and set some sort of flag so that, on the subsequent call, the program knows to cleanup and/or delay to ensure it works without issue.

There's some github issues that I've looked at that seem to be running into similar problems - solutions are generally forced delays or (in a perfect world) not having a device that disconnects initially. I'll link some for context:

[PlatformException(set_notification_error, error when writing the descriptor, null) on setNotifyValue #295](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/295)

[Characteristics are sending duplicate notifications when device is reconnected #525](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/525) (Not *exactly* the same, but duplicate firing makes me think it's not too far off)

Either way, thanks for reading and I hope to be past this thorn in my side soon!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to offend you, but your code is very hard to read. First I suggest that you should use some conventions. Like Future, curly braces after if, break that enormous method into smaller ones.
I have seen this error before. Here I suggest some options to solve.

- In the switch, you are starting to listen to one stream. At the end
  of your function, you are trying to read a characteristic. I'm not
  sure if your POC supports more than one method at the same time. I
  would remove readServiceCharacteristics while you listen to the
  stream or start with reading and wait until it's finished and then
  start the stream listener.
- It's hard to tell what is happening when
  you notify the listeners perhaps you try to read or write on the BLE
  device. Remove it. See what happens.

So basically try to use the characteristics one by one and try to avoid parallel requests.
Hope it help!